# Louvre tickets purchased online but not printed

Tags: tickets, online-resources, paris, sightseeing, the-louvre

Is it possible to purchase Louvre tickets online, and then gain admittance by showing the e-ticket on a smartphone?

I may be able to get the tickets printed, but it's more flexible if I can just buy the tickets wherever I am, then show my phone.

Comment: Please review the [help] for the conventions and standards for questions; asking for people to share their experiences is specifically against the guidelines across all of StackExchange. What does the Louvre say about requirements for entry on its website?

Comment: Asking people for experiences like this is bad practice for this site. We don't want duplicates of the same answer being placed, which any "what's your experience of X?" question will lead too. I'm going to edit your question to get the exact same information, but without the request for a list of experiences. Feel free to roll back, or continue editing if you don't like it.

Comment: Yesterday I purchased the six day museum pass from the tourism center 25 Rue du Pyramides. It is a physical ticket and it allows six consecutive days of access to Paris museums. It confers the advantage of breezing through the Lions entrance and skipping the lines. I have not found an online (smartphone) ticketing mechanisms for the Louvre admittance

Answer (score 7):

**The ticket must have been printed prior to your visit** at least in principle, but it seems they may agree, at their own discretion, to print it for you if you have forgotten it (or claim to...). From the [Terms and Conditions](https://www.ticketlouvre.fr//louvre/b2c/index.cfm/CGV#4) (the link is to the French version; the language can be changed using the list at the top-right corner):

> The ticket must have been printed by the buyer prior to their visit,
>   with no changes to the print size, in full page view, on white A4
>   paper, blank on both sides. Partially or incorrectly printed, soiled,
>   damaged or illegible tickets will not be valid. The buyer is required
>   to check the details and condition of the tickets purchased online and
>   printed.
>
> No ticket purchased online may be collected on site.
>
> If a
>   ticket has been forgotten, damaged, incorrectly printed or has an
>   error in the ticket-holder's name, the EPML reserves the right to
>   reprint it in order to assist with the visitor admission process.